# How to launch ros node with gdb on terminator terminal?

Tags: gdb, ros, terminator

I am currently running a **ros** node with `launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"` attribute as described at [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) to debug with **gdb**.

My current terminal emulator is [terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#).

How can I run the node on my preferred terminal emulator **terminator**?

I tried to change `launch-prefix` as `launch-prefix="terminator -e gdb --args"` but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried the `--execute` parameter as described in the [documentation](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advancedusage.html#command-line-options) of terminator? You would set `launch-prefix="terminator --execute gdb --args"`.

Comment: Right. `gdb` starts on terminator now. However, there are some problems such as `error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. xterm works without any error. I should also change one more thing.

Comment: I see, then `xterm` and `terminator` set up your environment variables differently. You could extend the launch-prefix to something like `launch-prefix="terminator -e source MY_CONFIG && gdb --args` where MY_CONFIG refers to a file which sets up your environment variables correctly. You can find that out, e.g., by running `env` in a normal console, where starting the node works. Then copy set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable accordingly in your MY_CONFIG script.